# Que hacer para que el resultado de un calculo con un loop se guarde en mi df?

Tags: r

Mi intención con el siguiente código es dividir dos `df` en base al campo `date`, para luego aplicar un calculo y que se guarde el resultado de cada fecha en un único `df`. Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
for (i in unique(temp_maxmin$date))
     Tmaxmin_subset<- temp_maxmin[temp_maxmin$date==i,]
    radiosond_subset<-radiosond[radiosond$date==i,]
    basedata<-as.data.frame(seq(2500,10000,50))
    colnames(basedata)<-c("height")
    basedata$date<-Tmaxmin_subset$date
    basedata$Tmax<-(Tmaxmin_subset$max_val[[1]]-(9.8/1000*(basedata$height-radiosond_subset$height[[1]])))
    basedata$Classic<-(Tmaxmin_subset$classic[[1]]-(9.8/1000*(basedata$height-radiosond_subset$height[[1]])))
    basedata$ICU<-(Tmaxmin_subset$icubogota[[1]]-(9.8/1000*(basedata$height-radiosond_subset$height[[1]])))
```

Estoy teniendo algunos problemas, de primera mano y el mas importante es que no se están guardando todas los datos correspondientes a cada fecha si no la ultima fecha. Ademas, no he encontrado una linea en la cual pueda decir que solo se haga el calculo cuando los subsets coincidan en la fecha y de resto omita hacer el calculo.

Muestra de los df

```
        date  max_val  min_val  classic icubogota
      <date>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 2006-04-17 290.4017 283.5183 288.5183  286.5183
2 2006-04-18 291.9247 283.2837 288.2837  286.2837
3 2006-04-19 292.3280 283.9537 288.9537  286.9537
4 2006-04-20 292.0320 284.1527 289.1527  287.1527
5 2006-04-21 290.8660 282.9913 287.9913  285.9913
6 2006-04-22 290.9757 282.6947 287.6947  285.6947



  press height   temp dwpt relh mixr drct sknt  thta  thte  thtv       date
1 753.0   2546 281.35  6.5   89 8.12    0    0 305.1 329.8 306.6 1999-03-11
2 740.0   2688 282.75  6.5   81 8.27   47    4 308.1 333.6 309.7 1999-03-11
3 735.1   2743 282.65  6.2   80 8.13   65    5 308.6 333.7 310.1 1999-03-11
4 708.2   3048 281.85  4.3   74 7.40  160   10 311.0 334.1 312.4 1999-03-11
5 700.0   3143 281.55  3.7   72 7.18  135    8 311.8 334.3 313.1 1999-03-11
6 682.4   3353 280.05  2.9   76 6.95  135    7 312.4 334.3 313.7 1999-03-11
```

Cualquier Ayuda es bien recibida

Comment: Y no utilizas `{ }` al comienzo y término del loop? Además, sin un `df` reproducible o de ejemplo, no se puede ayudar muy bien

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema de concepto. Dentro del ciclo `for`, por cada iteración estas haciendo:

```
basedata<-as.data.frame(seq(2500,10000,50))
```

Lo que te re-define cada vez de nuevo el `data.frame`, cada vuelta `basedata` vuelve a crearse en blanco y le completas los datos, por consiguiente al finalizar el ciclo `basedata` solo tendrá los valores de la última iteración.

Te aclaro que hay formas mucho mejores de resolver que usar un ciclo `for`, pero eso te lo dejo para que lo investigues. Tomando como base tu ejemplo, lo que puedes hacer es:

```
temp_maxmin <- read.table(text="date max_val min_val classic icubogota
2006-04-17 290.4017 283.5183 288.5183 286.5183
2006-04-18 291.9247 283.2837 288.2837 286.2837
2006-04-19 292.3280 283.9537 288.9537 286.9537
2006-04-20 292.0320 284.1527 289.1527 287.1527
2006-04-21 290.8660 282.9913 287.9913 285.9913
2006-04-22 290.9757 282.6947 287.6947 285.6947", sep=" ", header=TRUE)

radiosond <- read.table(text="press height temp dwpt relh mixr drct sknt thta thte thtv date
753.0 2546 281.35 6.5 89 8.12 0 0 305.1 329.8 306.6 1999-03-11
740.0 2688 282.75 6.5 81 8.27 47 4 308.1 333.6 309.7 2006-04-17
735.1 2743 282.65 6.2 80 8.13 65 5 308.6 333.7 310.1 2006-04-17
708.2 3048 281.85 4.3 74 7.40 160 10 311.0 334.1 312.4 1999-03-11
700.0 3143 281.55 3.7 72 7.18 135 8 311.8 334.3 313.1 1999-03-11
682.4 3353 280.05 2.9 76 6.95 135 7 312.4 334.3 313.7 2006-04-22", sep=" ", header=TRUE)

basedata<-data.frame()
for (i in unique(temp_maxmin$date)) {
    Tmaxmin_subset <- temp_maxmin[temp_maxmin$date==i,]
    radiosond_subset <- radiosond[radiosond$date==i,]

    if (nrow(Tmaxmin_subset)!= 0 & nrow(radiosond_subset)!=0) {
        tmp<-as.data.frame(seq(2500,10000,50))
        colnames(tmp)<-c("height")

        tmp$date <- Tmaxmin_subset$date
        tmp$Tmax <- (Tmaxmin_subset$max_val[[1]]-(9.8/1000*(tmp$height-radiosond_subset$height[[1]])))
        tmp$Classic <- (Tmaxmin_subset$classic[[1]]-(9.8/1000*(tmp$height-radiosond_subset$height[[1]])))
        tmp$ICU <- (Tmaxmin_subset$icubogota[[1]]-(9.8/1000*(tmp$height-radiosond_subset$height[[1]])))

        if (nrow(basedata)==0) {
            basedata <- tmp
        } else {
            basedata <- rbind(as.matrix(basedata), as.matrix(tmp))
        }
    }
}
```

Comentarios:

- `basedata` lo creamos fuera del ciclo como un `data.frame` vació
- Agregué un control para estar seguros que el proceso se ejecuta solo si tenemos datos de los dos `data.farmes` de entrada: `if (nrow(Tmaxmin_subset)!= 0 & nrow(radiosond_subset)!=0)`
- Luego creamos un `data.frame` temporal y lo completamos con tu lógica
- Si es el primer ciclo (`nrow(basedata)==0`) le asignamos a `basedata` el valor de `tmp`, caso contrario usamos [`rbind()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cbind.html) para "agregar" `tmp` a `basedata`

Comment: Gracias Patricio. Podrías indicarme en donde puedo investigar mas del tema que mencionas antes, quisiera entender la mejor forma de realizar esto.

Comment: No se si te pueda orientar mucho, lo que veo es que todo el código se podría eventualmente expresar como operaciones de combinación entre dataframes sin necesidad de iterar con un ciclo for, que suele menos performante, pero es algo relativo que dependerá del volumen de datos. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías echarle un vistazo al paquete Tidyverse o data.table, te permite trabajar con data frames con las mejores opciones. Además creo que también te vendría bien echarle un vistazo a Purrr, con las funciones "map" que te permiten aplicar funciones a través de listas y/o data frames. (Te contesto y no comento porque con la repu que tengo en español no me permite) Un saludo y espero que te ayude.